# Minecraft, Java, Ubuntu and a SOCKS proxy

Tags: proxy, minecraft

How is it possible to run a java game like Minecraft behind a SSH tunnel (SOCKS proxy). I configured the proxy in Oneiric in the system settings and Ubuntu One, Pidgin, and so on works. But not the java game Minecraft. What can I do?

This solution did not work:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=HOST -Dhttp.proxyPort=PORT -Dhttps.proxyHost=HOST -Dhttps.proxyPort=PORT -Xmx1000m -jar XXXXXXX.jar
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Isn't SOCKS setup with `-DsocksProxyHost=HOST`?

Comment: I think it might be, @Lekensteyn, however Minecraft by default doesn't like proxies much, unless *all* your inet traffic is routed through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MineCraft does not have support for proxying of data.  In Java, in order to support proxies, you need to have that support compiled in, or change your networking settings to use a proxy.

However, Minecraft does not look at the network settings, so unless your proxy is set to *all* Internet traffic being sent via a proxy (which sometimes breaks things), it will not work.

*(Setting up proxy support in Java apps can be a pain, so I understand why the Minecraft devs left that out)*